# My brother has a much higher download speed than me. HOW?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, download, storage, internet-speed

My brother just bought his first pc. He has been getting around 20MB/s in download speed. Meanwhile my highest download speed is around 5MB/s. I can recall my pc reaching 20MB/s in download speed but this is very rare and and so I know it's possible for my pc to reach those speeds. Can the problem be my SSD or hard drive?

Here are my specs:

- Motherboard B450M BAZOOKA (MS-7A38)
- Processor    AMD Ryzen 5 2600 Six-Core Processor, 3400 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)
- 16 GB of ram
- GPU AMD RX580
- TP link AC gaming WLAN adapter (for my wifi connection)

Comment: The most obvious question is whether your brother is using the same network connection as you.

Comment: Are both devices using Wi-Fi? We'll need exact Wi-Fi specs or exact brand and model#'s of their Wi-Fi adapters. Same for your wireless router. Also, are both devices joining the 5GHz band of the router?

Answer (score 0):

## Performing the same speed test on both devices

It often depends on what you are downloading. A good test would be to download the same thing or perform the same speed test. I always use https://fast.com to get a quick benchmark of the network speed on devices connected to the internet. Don't do this at the same time on each device, but run them one right after the other.

## Checking the link speed on both devices

In order to see what your maximum (link) speed is, you can open **Network Connections** in Control Panel quickly by right-clicking your start menu in the bottom left-hand corner, then press `Run`. Then type `ncpa.cpl` and press enter. Find the connection that has your wifi name, or sometimes it will have green bars next to it showing your signal strength. Right-Click on that connection and click **Status**. You will get a dialog like [the one below](https://www.jdhodges.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/2019-01-30-16_37_06-Windows-10-Wi-Fi-Speed-Network-Status.png) and next to `Speed:` you will see the `maximum speed` you can get.

[image]